# What's the point of Django's collectstatic?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files, collectstatic

In Django, the convention is to put all of your static files (i.e css, js) specific to your app into a folder called **static**. So the structure would look like this:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/ --> (settings.py, etc)
    myapp/ --> (models.py, views.py, etc)
        static/
```

In `mysite/settings.py` I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
```

So when I run the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

It creates a folder called `staticfiles` at the root level (so same directory as `myapp/`)

What's the point of this? Isn't it just creating a copy of all my static files?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Collect static files from multiple apps into a single path

Well, a single Django *project* may use several *apps*, so while there you only have one `myapp`, it may actually be `myapp1`, `myapp2`, etc

By copying them from inside the individual apps into a single folder, you can point your frontend web server (e.g. nginx) to that single folder `STATIC_ROOT` and serve static files from a single location, rather than configure your web server to serve static files from multiple paths.

### Persistent URLs with [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage)

A note about the MD5 hash being appended to the filename for versioning: It's not part of the default behavior of `collectstatic`, as `settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE` defaults to `StaticFilesStorage` (which doesn't do that)

The MD5 hash will kick in e.g. if you set it to use `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`, which adds that behavior.

> The purpose of this storage is to keep serving the old files in case
> some pages still refer to those files, e.g. because they are cached by
> you or a 3rd party proxy server. Additionally, it’s very helpful if
> you want to apply far future Expires headers to the deployed files to
> speed up the load time for subsequent page visits.

Comment: you want to say that it will be easy to find for the web server to serve the static content

Answer (score 62):

Django static files can be in many places. A file that is served as `/static/img/icon.png` could [come from many places](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders). By default:

- `FileSystemFinder` will look for `img/icon.png` in each of `STATICFILES_DIRS`,
- `AppDirectoriesFinder` will look for `img/icon.png` in the `static` subfolder in each of your `INSTALLED_APPS`. This allows libraries like Django Admin to add their own static files to your app.

Now: this only works if you run `manage.py runserver` with DEBUG=1. When you go live, the Django process will no longer serve the static assets. It would be inefficient to use Django for serving these, there are more specialised tools specifically for that.

Instead, you should do something like this:

- find all of static files from every app
- build a single directory that contains all of them
- upload them somewhere (a `static` directory somewhere on your webserver or a third-party file storage)
- configure your webserver (such as nginx) to serve `/static/*` directly from that directory and redirect any other requests to Django.

`collectstatic` is a ready-made script that prepares this directory for you, so that you can connect it directly to your deployment script.

Comment: Updated link for how Django finds static files: [come from many places](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders)

Answer (score 28):

In the production installation, you want to have persistent URLs. The URL doesn't change unless the file content changes.

This is to prevent having clients to have wrong version of CSS or JS file on their computer when opening a web page from Django. Django staticfiles detects file changes and updates URLs accordingly, so that if CSS or JS file changes the web browser downloads the new version.

This is usually achieved by adding MD5 hash to the filename during `collectstatic` run.

Edit: Also see related answer to multiple apps.

Comment: Good one! didnot know it

Comment: "usually achieved by adding MD5 hash" you mean [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage)? Nice, I haven't seen that

Comment: I think by default there is no MD5 hashing going on, since `settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE` defaults to `StaticFilesStorage`, so the MD5 will kick in only after you e.g. set it to `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`, am I correct?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa But then how does the frontend app know to which file name it should link since the latter always changes ?

Comment: @lapin Good question! Naturally there needs to exist 1) mapping to the latest versions and 2) way to communicate this. Usually it is stored in a file somewhere and then when you ask "which full URL for latest version of X" it gives you out a result.

Answer (score 16):

It's useful when there are multiple django apps within the site.

`collectstatic` will then collect static files from all the apps in one place - so that it could be served up in a production environment.