# ValueError at / Missing staticfiles manifest entry for ''

Tags: django

I'm trying to migrate from Django 1.9.7 to Django 1.11.5. I have three different django apps, and they are pretty much the same regarding packages and settings. I have deployed all three of them to a web server and two apps are working without any problems, but third one gives me headache - i get this error all the time:

```
ValueError at / Missing staticfiles manifest entry for ''
```

Here are the most relevant settings from `settings.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from settings import * 

SECRET_KEY = '***'

SITE_ID = 3

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost', 
    '127.0.0.1',
    '.example.com',
    '.example.com.',

    ]

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'storages',
    'example',
    'example2',
    'el_pagination',
    'debug_toolbar',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'example.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'example.wsgi.application'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'web@example.com'

MANAGERS = ADMINS

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS': 'default',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS': '300',
        'DEFAULT_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX': '',
    }
}

PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
)

#AWS_HEADERS = {  # see http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
#       'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
#        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
#S    }

# AMAZON S3 & CLOUDFRONT SERVING MEDIA FILES
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '***'
AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN = '***.cloudfront.net'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "***"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "***"
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'example/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/%s/' % MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
MEDIA_URL = '//%s/%s/' % (AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'example.custom_storages.MediaStorage'

# WHITENOISE SERVING STATIC FILES
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '***/static/example') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I don't know why i'm getting this error because i did nothing different (while deploying) comparing to the other two apps which are working regularly. Settings are almost the same! I've also tried to empty .css files so i could throw away possibility that css files are somewhere pointing to files that doesn't exist, but it didn't help. I've updated all of the packages that my websites are using. 
This app is working normally under Django 1.9.7, but i can't make it to work under 1.11.5.

**EDIT - HOW DID I FIX THIS?**

Thanks to @evansd's answer i've managed to find the problem! In one of my templates i've had this code which messed the whole thing up:

```
{% for num in numbers  %}
<li>
   <img src="{% static ''%}img/header/{{num}}.jpg" alt="image {{num}}"/>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

and i've changed it to:

```
{% for num in numbers  %}
<li>
   <img src="{% static 'img/header/'|addstr:num|addstr:'.jpg' %}" alt="image {{num}}">
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

After this fix everything works well! For custom addstr template tag look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386168/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-django-templates/23783666#23783666).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that somewhere in your templates you're referencing a static file that doesn't exist. Specifically, your passing an empty string to `static`. Perhaps you have a line like `{% static some_variable %}` where `some_variable` is undefined?

In Django 1.11 the behaviour changed so that errors are thrown on missing files. See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage.manifest_strict

If you fix this reference then everything should work.

Comment: In my case, it was just that the `favicon.ico` file was missing. Rather brutal to have the entire server shut down only in production with 500 for this.

Comment: I think so too @Overdrivr, it's just too much. This kind of an error shouldn't halt the server. Why can't the missing files just be 404'd?

Answer (score 4):

Not running following ( `python manage.py collectstatic` ) may be your issue.

#### Solution:

You can circumvent this issue and improve the code by moving the `static()` call out of the model field and changing the default value to the string `"pledges/images/no-profile-photo.png"`. It should look like this:

`avatar_url = models.URLField(default='pledges/images/no-profile-photo.png')`

When you access `avatar_url`, use either

1. (frontend / Django Templates option) `{% static profile_instance.avatar_url %}`, where `profile_instance` is a context variable referring to a Profile object.
2. (backend / Python option) use `static(profile_instance.avatar_url)`.

#### Explanation:

By using the result of `static()` for a default value, the app is putting a URL in the database that includes the `STATIC_URL` prefix -- which is like hard-coding it because data won't change when `settings.py` does. More generally, you shouldn't store the results of `static()` in the database at all.

If you ensure that you're using the `{% static %}` tag or `static()` function each time you're accessing `avatar_url` for display on the frontend, `STATIC_URL` will still be added based on your environment config at runtime.

[This SO thread has a lot of good content on staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586114/whats-the-point-of-djangos-collectstatic)

#### Why the error is happening:

It looks like you have a circular dependency:

1. `collectstatic` needs to run in order to create `manifest.json`
2. your application needs to load in order to run `manage.py` commands, which calls `static()`
3. `static()` relies on an entry in `manifest.json` to resolve.

Source answer here.
[Django Model: ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for "file_name.ext"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009055/django-model-valueerror-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-for-file-name-ext)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running django inside a docker, but not as a root user.
From outside, I was running `python manage.py collectstatic`. This runs `manage.py` as root user, making the files unaccessible to django itself.

Solution: Run the command as the same user you are running django inside your docker, or follow up with a `chown` command for your `static` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error when running tests after installing whitenoise. That was configured in main settings, but the test runner wasn't running it. So I fixed it by overriding an entry in the STORAGES dictionary in `test_settings.py` with the Django default:

```
STORAGES["staticfiles"]["BACKEND"] = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage"
```