# How to set Heroku profile so it accepts "yes" in any terminal question for Heroku Deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to run a command while deploying my Django code to Heroku. I want to accept any question it might get in terminal.

I tried to add following to the procfile, but it didn't work.

```
release: python manage.py collectstatic --yes
release: python manage.py collectstatic -y
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue while deploying Django project on Heroku. Like it was suggested before, if you run through Git, Heroku will run the command for you. So, if you still get error on heroku and not locally that means you havent add all the files to git before pushing. Try that it should work.

If the problem still persist, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46479378/valueerror-at-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-for)

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for this command is `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`. However, if your using Git to deploy, Heroku should already run this command for you.

Comment: I tried that too.. deploying from Git I keep getting this error ```ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'css/bootstrap.min.css'``` It complies properly on local but gives an error on Heroku