# `FileNotFoundError`: when issue `python manage.py collectstatic`

Tags: django

When I tried to issue commands to collect staticfiles

```
In [41]: ! python manage.py collectstatic
```

It throw `FileNotFoundError:`

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/static'
```

Nevertheless, there exist file '/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/static'

```
In [44]: ! tree -L 2
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── forum
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── forums
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── ll_forum
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   ├── pyvenv.cfg
│   └── share
└── manage.py

14 directories, 15 files
```

The setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #my apps
    "forums"
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), #notice the comma
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586172/5442966

Comment: @JuniorGantin It's not the good answer according to his issue.

Comment: Note that you don't have to set `STATIC_ROOT` or run `collectstatic` until you deploy your project into production. Since you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, `runserver` will take care of serving static files for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings, by default Django looks for a directory named `static` in your root project, so that 's why your get this ``` /Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/static'``FileNotFoundError ``` the folder is not present.

You have that directory `static` next to your settings, it should not be there. By the way also your templates should not be there.

Move them back to your root project

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── forum
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
|   |---static # remove this
│   ├── templates # remove this here
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
|---static -- # GOOD
|---templates # GOOD
```

Comment: but why the official tutorial recommend to include templates and static in apps?

Comment: You can do so, but where you had put it, that director was not an app at all... apps are those that have been created by this command `manage.py startapp app_name`

Comment: I got your idea now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have static directory outside from Django App. This directory and your Django app should be separate.

Then, if you specify :

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), #notice the comma
)
```

It means your static directory is in your base directory. Or you have only `forum`, `forums`, `ll_forum` ...

If you want absolutly keep your static directory in your Django App, make this directory in the `BASE_DIR` (move from initial position to your base project) and write something like this in settings.py file :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')
```

Finally, you should have something like this :

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── forum
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── forums
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── ll_forum
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   ├── pyvenv.cfg
│   └── share
└── manage.py
│
└── static
│
└── templates
```

Comment: The official tutorial recommend to include templates and static in apps.