# How to add static file in django before pushing

Tags: django

I'm coding css and javascript file for my web  project. That files I put in app folder. I use "git add ." and "git push origin +(branch_name)", but I clone project again, I don't call that static files I wrote. How do I solve problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your query is a little unclear to proceed with exact solution*

Still, collect-static does the job for static files in Django.
A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586172/7222196) issue was raised, which can be of help to you.

Answer (score -1):

for me the following command do the trick:
***python manage.py collectstatic***

But plz note that it also depends on the way like where you would like to host your static files and so on. For example, I use azure storage account to host the static files, therefore in my case I have to configure the setting.py also.

Hope you can solve ur problem soon. (btw surprise to know the leaf village uses django, too... )

Comment: the static files I wrote don't added, so if use this above command, cannot call static files