# Why is my .css file not fully rendering on server, but working locally?

Tags: python, html, css, django

Essentially, my style.css file is only partially rendering on the live server, despite working properly in my local development environment. Prior to this update I just pushed, things were working fine - I changed some content in the .css file, but not the content that is being affected by this issue.

The parts of the CSS file that seem to be affected:

```
table.student {
    width:  75%;
    border: 3px inset;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

table.admin {
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px inset;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1{
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 1%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The rest of the .css file is being applied just fine.

I didn't change the file location (`myapp/static/css/style.css`), or how/where the file is called (in my base.html file with the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">`).

I have run collectstatic with no discernible effect. The python version I am using is 3.7.2

Comment: Use google dev tools to investigate your DOM and to debug it. Since most parts of the .css seem to be applied the file is loaded properly by the server.

Comment: Please add settings.py code for `static path`.

Comment: try **collect static** - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586114/whats-the-point-of-djangos-collectstatic

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have righted itself with no further editing/investigation - possibly a caching issue.